# PHP imap_search not working in Sent folder

Tags: php, imap, email

I am integrating an email box feature into a PHP web application and I need to be able to search through my emails using a filter on the subject. Specifically, I need to search for the emails which contain a certain keyword in their subject.

To do that, I am using the **imap_search** function.

When I use imap_search in my INBOX folder, it works fine and I do get the emails I am looking for.

But if I try to use imap_search in any other folder (for example, my Sent folder), zero email get returned, even if I use a keyword that I know is featured in some of my emails' subjects

I am successfully connecting to my Sent folder using imap_open.
Additionally, imap_sort manages to fetch all the emails in the folder 
It is only when I try imap_search that I have an issue.

My code :

```
//the path for the sent folder was confirmed by using imap_list()
$sent = imap_open("{imap.mydomain.com:143/novalidate-cert}Sent", $login, $pwd);

$search = "SUBJECT \"test\"";

imap_sort($sent, SORTDATE, 1);   //this works and returns an array of emails
imap_search($sent, $search);     //this returns bool(false)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$seach $ "SUBJECT \"test\"";` doesn't look like valid code.  Can you update this with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Max you're right, I just edited my question.

Comment: I would guess server bug, since there should be no difference between INBOX and Sent.  If you can, try using a socket client (socat, telnet, openssl s_client) and sending the raw commands to see if you reproduce.  `tag LOGIN user password`, `tag SELECT Sent`, `tag UID SEARCH SUBJECT "test"`.

Comment: @Max I did try connecting using telnet and found out that there is indeed a bug with the server. Thank you for your help.